# Android Image Capture does not save file

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I am following the example at https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

I had it working briefly, then started enhancing the code, and now after taking a photo, it no longer gets stored in the file system.

```
private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    val imageCaptureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    val componentName = imageCaptureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (componentName == null) {
        Log.e("Ztuph", "componentName == null, cannot takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager))")
    }
    else try {
        val photoFile = createImageFile()
        val authority = "com.ztuph.android.FileProvider"
        try {
            photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authority, photoFile)
            Log.d("Ztuph", "1 photoUri = $photoUri")
            imageCaptureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri)
            startActivityForResult(imageCaptureIntent, RequestCode.IMAGE_CAPTURE.ordinal)
            Log.d("Ztuph", "startActivityForResult(imageCaptureIntent, RequestCode.IMAGE_CAPTURE.ordinal)")
        }
        catch (illegalArgumentException: IllegalArgumentException) {
            // TODO
        }
    }
    catch (ioException: IOException) {
        // TODO Error occurred while creating the File
        Log.e("Ztuph", "can't create file", ioException)
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {

    when (requestCode){
        RequestCode.IMAGE_CAPTURE.ordinal -> when (resultCode){
            Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "IMAGE_CAPTURE result canceled")
            }
            Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: requestCode = IMAGE_CAPTURE, resultCode = RESULT_OK")
                if (intent == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "intent == null")

                    val mediaScanIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE)
                    mediaScanIntent.data = photoUri
                    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent)
                    Log.d(TAG, "broadcast Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE) with $photoUri")
                }
                else {
                    if (photoUri == null) Log.e(TAG, "photoUri == null")
                    else Log.d(TAG, "2 photoUri = $photoUri")

                    val mediaScanIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE)
                    mediaScanIntent.data = photoUri
                    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent)
                    Log.d(TAG, "broadcast Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE) with $photoUri")
                }
            }
            else -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot handle resultCode = $resultCode")
            }
        }
        else -> {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot handle requestCode = $requestCode")
        }
    }
}
```

There does not seem to be anything in the Logcat to indicate a problem.

It also runs differently on the emulator vs a real device (Galaxy Note 8). On the real device, it creates the directory "SD Card > Android > data > com.ztuph.android > files > Pictures" but nothing gets stored there. Also, the argument intent in onActivityResult is null.

On the emulated (Nexus 5X API 27) I cannot tell if the directory is being created (the Files app is too primitive), but there are no files any more. Yesterday, my app was creating image.jpg file, and today it is not. Also, on the emulator, the argument intent in onActivityResult is not null.

My manifest looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ztuph.android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="aia-compat-api-min-version"
            android:value="1" />
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.ztuph.android.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Does anyone have any troubleshooting tips, or other ideas why the image capture would stop writing to the file system?

Answer (score 1):

> There does not seem to be anything in the Logcat to indicate a problem.

Most likely it does, but the error would be coming from the camera app, as it has no ability to write to your desired location. Add `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` to your `Intent`.

> It also runs differently on the emulator vs a real device (Galaxy Note 8).

There are hundreds of pre-installed camera apps across the ~10,000 Android device models. There are hundreds of other camera apps that the user might install. Whenever you invoke a third-party app, you are prone to get different results.

> Also, the argument intent in onActivityResult is null.

It is supposed to be `null`.

> I cannot tell if the directory is being created (the Files app is too primitive)

Use the Device File Explorer in Android Studio 3.0+.

Comment: `imageCaptureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)` does the trick :-)